# Implement Forgot Password/Email Verification django rest with ReactJS

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, forgot-password

I want to implement forgot password or email verification with django and react,

To implement forgot password I used django rest auth.Here below urls are:

```
url(
    r'^rest-auth/password/reset/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset',
),
url(
    r'^rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/'
    r'(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

I have successfully hit the request to first url from my react js front end,and I also received the email with token and uid, but the link redirects me to django rest native UI however I want to be in react framework UI.

So how can I implement this? is there any suitable way to implement forgot password with react and django as it is not done by django rest auth because the flow of react front end disturbs.

Comment: As far as I understand you need to redirect to frontend from verification link and the rest handle in there. On frontend site you will send a post with token and uuid to the backend and once you get 200 from backend the user is verified.

Comment: How can I get that token from verification link

Comment: You can get help from this article: https://medium.com/@arifulislam_ron/email-verification-in-django-and-react-141dd7caf017

Answer (score 0):

So in order to obtain a token from verification link you could use a lib like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string). Basically you pass location and go on from there, documentation is pretty reach so you should have no problem.